# Issue with shadow copies in 2012 R2 file server cluster

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, file-server, vss, shadow-copies

I have recently created a 2012 R2 file server cluster, and am trying to enable shadow copies.

When I right click the drive containing user data within the failover cluster manager, and click properties, I can go to the Shadow Copies tab.

If I select the volume from the list, click enable, and set a schedule, it seems to accept the settings. However, even if I delete the default schedules, and create a custom one, the scheduled task on the node does not show my custom schedule, and instead only shows the default 7am and 12pm on weekday triggers.

I am wondering if there is a bug in cluster manager, than prevents me from setting custom schedules?

I was also wondering if anyone can advise how shadow copies is then handled during a failover, as the scheduled task seems to only be created on the node currently running the role.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I have answered my second question by failing the role over to another node, and found the scheduled task disappears from the original node, and appears on the second node. I think there must also be a bug in cluster manager, because the scheduled task that has failed over and back, now shows the custom schedule I specified when creating originally.